# Creating Kibana Dashboard based on Malware

Tags: kibana, dashboard, elk, malware, malware-detection

I am thinking of creating a Kibana Dashboard to detect malware by the use of graphs/visualizations. Anyone have any ideas on how I can implement a dashboard based on different visualizations of network traffic to create this dashboard?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide more details of what you want to achieve and give examples.